# How to remove an empty new line when copying to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Using this code in a chrome extension to create a text in textarea value and copy to clipboard, the value needs to be pasted into Excel, that's why "\t" (next column), in the last column (final[0].textContent) contains an address so there are new lines there which is okay.

The problem is when I paste it in Notepad for example: it starts with a new line and then my text follows. How can I get rid of that first empty line?

```
elClipboard.value = strDate + "\t" + elQuantity[1].childNodes[0].textContent +
  "\t\"" + final[0].textContent + "\"";

document.body.appendChild(elClipboard);
var selection = document.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(elClipboard);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
document.execCommand("copy");

selection.removeAllRanges();
document.body.removeChild(elClipboard);
```

Comment: There's no need to use getSelection and range, remove it, and simply do the following: elClipboard.focus(); elClipboard.select(); document.execCommand("copy");